# CentOS7 VPS: Install WordPress with existing MySQL and httpd

Tags: php, apache-2.4, wordpress, mariadb, lamp

Requirement: Install Wordpress in CentOs 7 VPS

Currently available:

Apache : Server version: Apache/2.4.35 (IUS), Server built: Dec 8 2018 02:08:22

MySQL : mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.47, for Linux (x86_64) using EditLine wrapper
Questions:

Should I install LAMP on top of this or should I just install new PHP version with yum?
MySQL is currently used by other applications running on Tomcat. Will these be affected if I install MariaDB with LAMP stack?
Also why is mysql -v and mysql --version giving two different results?

> mysql --version > mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.47, for Linux (x86_64) using EditLine wrapper

> mysql -v > ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.   ```-v``` is for verbose logging.   ```--version``` is for version.  Also, not a good idea to install mariadb on a system that has mysql.   If you need to do that,  have mariadb use a different port and use a different home dir.

Comment: So I can update the php version and install WordPress without having to install the LAMP stack. Do you think the shown version information is too old?

Comment: Why can't you just set WordPress to use MySQL?

Comment: I will do that. I need to install a newer version of php to get it working. So I was wondering if the apache and mysql versions are too old.